# Follow playlists using Spotify iOS SDK

Tags: ios, spotify

My requirement is to add a track to a particular playlist using the Spotify iOS SDK, and to make sure the user is following that playlist. In general adding a track is fine unless the user has deleted the playlist in Spotify (which actually just unfollows it), in this case the track is added, but the user cannot see the playlist anymore.

If the user isn't following the playlist, can we follow playlists using the SDK?

Thanks

Jules

Answer (score 0):

Yeah just use SPTFollow ([API documentation](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/Classes/SPTFollow.html#//api/name/createRequestForFollowingPlaylist:withAccessToken:secret:error:)). Here's an example of a request in Swift 3:

```
var req = SPTFollow.createRequestFor(followingPlaylist: URL(string: "spotify:user:USERID:playlist:PLAYLISTID"), withAccessToken: (SPTAuth.defaultInstance().session.accessToken)!, secret: false)

SPTRequest.sharedHandler().perform(req) { (error, response, data) in
    print("error=\(error), response=\(response), data=\(data)"
    var results = SPTFollow.followingResult(from: data!, with: response!)
    print("is following? \(results[0])")
}
```

Comment: The SPTFollow api seems no longer being supported by Spotify iOS SDK. Do you know any replacement?